# Fulfill between two lineschart in seaborn FacetGrid

Tags: python, python-3.x, matplotlib, seaborn

I can draw 3 lines this way:

```
sns.lineplot(x="week", y="mean",    data=df)
sns.lineplot(x="week", y="min",     data=df)
sns.lineplot(x="week", y="max",     data=df)
```

So we have here min max and average value, they have precomputed before:

[image]

I want want fulfill with color between `min` and `max`, it have to look this way:
[image]

How to do that?

Comment: You can use `fill_between`

Comment: This question was not answered in the link provided and should not be closed. I'm trying to do the same in Seaborn so that I don't have to write a for loop over multiple axes with Matplotlib.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `matplotlib`

You are looking for [`matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.fill_between.html)

```
ax.fill_between(x, min, max)
```

see this link for a full example

https://matplotlib.org/2.0.1/examples/pylab_examples/fill_between_demo.html

## Link to `seaborn`

In the specific example of `seaborn` you need to first call the `facetgrid` function to populate the `facetgrid` with a blank plot.

Only then you can add lines in a `matplotlib` way whilst still using pretty `seaborn` formatting

See right at the bottom of the [`seaborn.FacetGrid`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.FacetGrid.html) docs and you will find an Attribute `ax` documented. In some versions this might also be `axes`

Comment: AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'fill_between'. Can we make it work with seaborn?

Comment: Are you not using `matplotlib` are you interested in plotting within `seaborn`?

Comment: I think, I will handle it with matplot lib,

Comment: I've updated with `seaborn`

Comment: g = sns.FacetGrid(df, row='Filename', height=3.0, aspect=4)

g = g.map(plt.plot, 'Time(min)', 'Smoothed Humidity')
x = plt.gca().axes.get_xlim()
for ax in g.axes:
    ax[0].fill_between(x, y1=85, y2=90, color=sns.xkcd_rgb['green'], alpha=0.2)